# Liscence Header and copyright info not merged by svn merge

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have created a branch called DEVELOPMENT, branched directly from the trunk. I have made a lot of changes to DEVELOPMENT branch and meanwhile other team members have made some commits to trunk.

Now I want to merge all the changes made by my team members on trunkto the DEVELOPMENT branch.

In my workspace that has the DEVELOPMENT branch checked out, I do

```
svn merge -r 17253:17330 svn+ssh://user.name@svn.xx.xxx.com/dag/svnroot/core/xxx/trunk .
```

It does report a number of conflicts.  All the conflicts are in the files that I have not touched.(Meaning the latest modification is in the TRUNK branch made by other team members).
I resolve all such conflicts with theris-conflict (tc)

However I have added a license notice at the beginning of all the C files in the trunk. I find that that has not been merged to the development branch. Is this a limitation of svn merge?

Comment: Nope, not a built-in limitation in general. Why would that change be treated differently than any other change? Was your license notice change in a revision included in the range of revisions you merged? Did somebody revert that change at some point?

Comment: No. it's **your** limitation of brainless-merge - you made all possible and impossible mistakes in process, i.e "All done Bad" in short

Comment: @LazyBadger - It would be good if you could explain a bit more??